# How to Uncheck all asp.net RadioButton Except Selected radio inside GridView using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, radio-button

I have a `RadioButton` inside `GridView`. I want to `Uncheck` all the asp.net `RadioButton` except the current Selected one using `JQuery`.
I have tried but no results..!

HTML MARKUP:

```
 <ItemTemplate> 
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbUser" runat="server" kID='<%# Eval("KID")%>' class="rdbUser"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".rdbUser", function() {
                var selectedRadio = $(this).attr('id');
                //var newrdo = $("input:radio.rdbUser:checked");
                //$(".rdbUser").prop('checked', false);
                //$('#' + selectedRadio).prop('checked', true);
                //$('input:radio[class=rdbUser]').prop('checked', false);
//                $('.rdbUser').removeAttr('checked');

                var kID = $(this).attr('kID');
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnKID").val(kID);
                //var payTypeID = $(this).attr('payTypeID');
                alert("selected Radio : " + kID);
            });
```

Here i get the `ID` of selected `RadioButton` but not able to set previous `selected` RadioButton to ?Uncheck. Help Appreciated!

Comment: GroupName Doesnt work when control is in GridView with Masterpages the Group names are autogenerated..! :(

Comment: `$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",false); $(this).prop("checked",true);`